# How to use JMF with Spring MVC 2.5?

Tags: spring-mvc, jmf

CaptureDeviceManager.getDeviceList(null)  works fine if I run my application using javac. But It returns null if I run it in tomcat after deploying it using Spring? What is the problem here? How to use JMF with Spring 2.5?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the JMF libraries are in the CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib directory rather than in your WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm using tomcat7. I copied all the jar files from jmf's lib folder to tomcat's lib folder. Still the problem exists.. Is that what you mean in your answer.